# Postgres stream replication master large diff between pg_current_xlog_location and sent_location

Tags: docker, postgresql-9.5

I have postgres master/slave stream replication setup, after performing heavy write operations into master using COPY, pg_xlogs folder starts piling up WAL segment files. After checking `pg_current_xlog_location` and `sent_location` on master, and `pg_last_xlog_receive_location` on slave, I found out that there's a huge difference between `pg_current_xlog_location` and `sent_location`, while `pg_last_xlog_receive_location` on slave indicating it's catching up with `sent_location`.

According to postgres documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-MONITORING), situation like this indicates master is under heavy load. while in my case I don't have anything else running after the COPY statement is done. How should I debug this?

Another thing worth mentioning is I'm running postgres 9.5 inside docker. Network between two host machines is 2Gbit/s.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the the archive_timeout is not set optimally. You can adjust this on how often you need to push this to slave.

WAL settings documentation: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Documentation home.
https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: Please post in the answer the main part of the link. If in the future that link is broken this answer will be useless